# Import a CSV Find an AD account by EmployeeID attribute and export to a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, attributes, import-csv, export-csv

Good morning,

I need a Powershell script to import a csv, find users by the EmployeeID attribute in AD, and export a csv verifying the account is disabled. I only need Display Name, employeeID, and Enable/Disabled in the export.

I am still very new to Powershell and I can usually cut/paste and manipulate existing scripts to do what I need, but I cannot seem to get this to work and now my code looks like swiss cheese after the mice got to it. Here is what I have, but I'm not sure if I'm even close to what is needed.

```
#Script Starts
$Users = Import-Csv "\folder\Test.csv"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$path = Split-Path -parent ".\folder\*.*"

#Create log date
$logdate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd-THH.mm.ss
$logfile = $path + "\logs\$logdate.logfile.txt"

ForEach ($User In $Users)
{
   # Retrieve values from the csv by header name.
   $FirstName = $User.FirstName
   $LastName = $User.LastName
   $ID = $User.Employee 

   #Search AD for Attributes
   $UserSN = (Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(employeeID=$ID)").sAMAccountName
   $UserDN = (Get-ADUser -Identity $UserSN -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName
   $Enabled = (Get-ADUser -Identity $UserSN -Properties Enabled).Enabled
   Export-Csv -Path $logdate.ADEnabled-Disabled.csv -Append
} 
#Finish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all these comments and the incomplete answer already given, I fear the OP gets confused even more...

In order for the OP to understand better, I stuck with his original code as much as possible.

**First**:

I'm assuming by looking at the code, the input csv file looks similar to this

```
"FirstName","LastName","Employee"
"Elvis","Presley","12345"
"Axl","Rose","987654"
"Janis","Joplin","654283"
```

The main problem i can see here is that the code is searching a AD user using the EmployeeID property (string). By using the filter as `eq` the string found in AD must be exactly what is in the csv (although case insensitive). If that is not the case the code will not find the user by using `-eq` but maybe, by comparing what is in the CSV and in AD, a different operator can be used such as `-like`. That is for the OP to figure out.

**Next the code**:

```
#Script Starts
$Users = Import-Csv "\folder\Test.csv"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$path = Split-Path -parent ".\folder\*.*"

# Create log date
$logdate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd-THH.mm.ss
$logfile = $path + "\logs\$logdate.logfile.txt"
# while you're at it, create the full path and filename for the output csv
$outFile = Join-Path $path $($logdate + ".ADEnabled-Disabled.csv")

# create an array for the output file
# You CAN do without by letting PowerShell do the aggregating of objects for you
# but in this case I think it will make things more readable to collect ourselves.
$result = @()
ForEach ($User In $Users) {
    # Find the user by the 'Employee' field in the csv and return an object with the required properties
    # Use -LDAPFilter which requires the LDAP syntax: "(employeeID=$($User.Employee))"
    # Or use -Filter where you use the Powershell syntax
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $($User.Employee)" -Properties DisplayName, Enabled, EmployeeID |
              Select-Object DisplayName, Enabled, EmployeeID

    if ($adUser) {
        # if the above statement did find the user, we add this to the result array
        $result += $adUser
    }
    else {
        $msg = "User '{0} {1}' not found. Check the Employee id {2}." -f $user.FirstName, $user.LastName, $user.Employee
        Write-Warning $msg
        Add-content $logfile -Value $msg
    }
} 

# now write the output csv as a new file. Because it has a complete date and time in the name
# the chances of overwriting an existing file are very slim indeed, but we'll use -Force anyway.
$result | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
#Finish
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this code is great, but please, bear with me as I understand it.
The `$result = @()` starts the array, which holds the data in memory and is the prefered/efficient way to do a csv comparison/search.
`ForEach ($User in $Users)` is the loop that holds each row ($User) in the csv ($Users)
`-Filter` uses the Employee column in the csv to search the EmployeeID attribute and only pulls the 3 properties, but it's the `Select-Object` statement that puts those 3 properties into the `$adUser` variable.
If found put the properties into the array Else Warning message.
When done create CSV.

Comment: You are spot on!

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll figure out this PowerShell thing (hopefully sooner than later) :D  I appreciate everyone's assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to `Export-Csv`, you need some type of input. Currently you are exporting nothing.

You ideally want to create an array of all your items, and export that array.

```
$x = @()
ForEach ($User In $Users)
{
   $x += [pscustomobject]@{
     FirstName = $User.FirstName
     LastName = $User.LastName
     #etc...
   }
} 

$x | Export-Csv -Path "$logdate.ADEnabled-Disabled.csv"
```

You have a number of small issues, but I think this will get you working towards actual results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now it's telling me Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized $UserSN = ...
Apparently my $ID variable is empty, I had it write to a log file and it's blank... What did I do wrong with that?

Comment: I fixed the blank $ID variable but still get "the search filter cannot be recognized" error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would print out `$User | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 10` and make sure you're using the correct property name/structure.

Comment: Not sure, any reason you're using -LDAPFilter over just -Filter?

Comment: I use -LDAPFilter because the script I copied that line from did it, -Filter doesn't work either, I get Operator Not supported when I change it to 
    $UserSN = (Get-ADUser -Filter "(employeeID=$ID)").sAMAccountName

Comment: -Filter has a different syntax. ``-Filter "employeeID -eq `"$ID`""`` or ``-Filter "employeeID -like `"*$ID*`""`` is correct iirc.

Comment: It's asking to avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to move this to chat? Do you have some time to chat with me about this?

Comment: I've been trying to work with the below line to get the Display Name but I can't figure it out. I keep getting the error The search Filter cannot be recognized.
 
$UserDN = (Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq `"$ID`"")

Comment: Seems like one of your fields is $null. I guess you can try adding the results of this `$PSVersionTable;get-module -all | ?{$_.name -eq 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management'} | select name,version` to your question too, maybe you're on an old version or something, if you're sure both those fields match.

Comment: Good points, but `$logdate.ADEnabled-Disabled.csv` without enclosing `"..."` _breaks_ the `Export-Csv` call. Also, it is much more efficient to simply collect the entire `foreach` statement's output in `$x` (rather than "add" to an array incrementally, which recreates it in every iteration), analogous to the following example: `$x = foreach ($num in 1..3) { $num * 2 }`. To avoid having to hold the entire collection in memory, use `Import-Csv | ForEach-Object ... | Export-Csv`.

Comment: I figured out that the displayName was pulling in as $Null so I replaced it with GivenName and SurName, I still couldn't get the `Export-CSV` to work, but I was able to get an `Out-File` command to work so I just did it that way. I can use Excel to make it CSV. My import file has some lines that are not in AD so I made an `IF` statement to separate them. I'll keep practicing and hopefully I can understand how to properly collect the entire `foreach` statement's output in `$x`.

Comment: Check my edit and @mklement0 's comment. Export-csv probably doesn't work because your lack of quotes to define $var.x as being $var+string, not $var+property.

Comment: I don't get far enough in the script when I do the 
`$result = @()
ForEach ($User In $Users)
{

 $result += [pscustomobject]@{`
It stops reading data from my import-csv file. So I get "The search filter cannot be recognized", but when I comment that out it works again. I'm sure it's something I'm doing with syntax as I play with it.
I'll have to look at it some more tomorrow, thanks for everything.

Comment: null row in the csv file?